# Unable to debug firebase functions

Tags: debugging, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-debugger

I am trying to debug my js code the runs on firebase functions.
My steps were:
install from functions

```
npm install --save @google-cloud/debug-agent
```

added index.js:

```
require('@google/cloud-debug').start();
```

when I tryed to run

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

got an error :

```
Error: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module '@google/cloud-debu
g'

Try running "npm install" in your functions directory before deployin
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The addition to `index.js` should be:

`require('@google-cloud/debug-agent').start();`

or better:

`require('@google-cloud/debug-agent').start({ allowExpressions: true });`

We recently renamed the module, and it is possible that the instructions you are following are partially out of date. Can you point us to the instructions you have been following?

Also note that support for debugging cloud functions is experimental at this point. There are certain cases (dependent on the traffic to the function) where you function may finish before the debug-agent has a chance to initialize/register. We're currently looking into how to address this.

Comment: do you know what files I should update to debug on https://console.cloud.google.com/debug is this only function folder? I tried to upload locally all the project/function folder but can't see any progress or ui changes. what can be the reason

Answer (score 0):

try: `ndb firebase serve`

debugger breakpoints are hit with stack traces visible, note it's a little slow so give the debugger time to instrument the child processes

Additionally I was able to debug cloud functions in isolation using (caps for removed values):

`GCLOUD_PROJECT=THE-FIREBASE-PROJECT node --inspect-brk /path/to/functions-framework --target FUNCTION-NAME --port=5000`

where functions-framework simply expands to the full path for the installed functions-framework (global in my case) and the working directory contains the target index.js for functions.

Alternately when or where the FIREBASE_CONFIG is needed try this format adjusted to fit:
`FIREBASE_CONFIG="{\"databaseURL\":\"https://YOUR-FIREBASE-PROJECT.firebaseio.com\",\"storageBucket\":\"YOUR-FIREBASE-PROJECT.appspot.com\",\"projectId\":\"YOUR-FIREBASE-PROJECT\"}`

- https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/ndb
- https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/functions-framework
- https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs/issues/15